# How to customize dexterity-through-the-web-content view?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I created a content in my Plone 4.3 site (no grok here) with the very nice Dexterity through-the-web editor. Now I'd like to customize the default view for this content.

I've read Martn Aspelli's book but the problem is that through-the-web content does'nt have a specific interface (so I can't use it to create my specific view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this all through-the-web, then do the following:

1. Create a template for your view in the "custom" folder of
   portal_skins (through the ZMI). You'll probably want to start with a
   copy of something like the page template
   (portal_skins/plone_content/document_view). Give it a name like
   your_content_type_view. Test it by appending /your_content_type_view
   to the URL for a sample object.
2. Edit the Factory Type Information (portal_types/your_content_type/Default 
   view method) to be your_content_type_view.

What you will have done is create a skin-level view for the type. This is different from the browser views that Martin is discussing, which do indeed require a class. The Dexterity development team is working on a way to provide TTW maintenance of browser views, but that's for a later version of Plone.

Meanwhile, if you later transfer your Dexterity content type to a Python add on, you'll be able to use your template, possibly unmodified for a browser view.

Comment: Ok thank you very much . I think I'm gonna try to do everything I want on my product (my new type declaration and the custom view)

Comment: One little problem : How could I retrieve my new fields in my custom_content_view ? (with through-the-web-content, and working in the "custom" folder)

Comment: Ok, I finally found myself the answer : <span tal:content="structure context/my_custom_rich_field/output" />